# Simplifying loop in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, loops, nested

I have this enormous loop in my code (not by choice), because I can't seem to make it work any other way. If there's some way make this simple as opposed to me repeating it +20 times that would be great, thanks.

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
     if (a[0] == 0xFF || b[i] == a[0]) {
         c[0] = b[i];
         if (d[0] == 0xFF) {
             d[0] = c[0];
         }

         ... below repeats +18 more times with [i+2,3,4,etc] ...

         if (a[1] == 0xFF || b[i + 1] == a[1]) {
             c[1] = b[i + 1];
             if (d[1] == 0xFF) {
                 d[1] = c[1];
             }

           ... when it reaches the last one it calls a method ...

           [self doSomething];
           continue;
           i += 19;

          ... then } repeats +19 times (to close things)...
      }
   } 
}
```

I've tried almost every possible combo of things that I know of attempting to make this smaller and efficient. Take a look at my flow chart — pretty huh? i'm not a madman, honest.

[image: flowin' oldskool style]

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us what this algorithm is meant to do and how it currently works. It would be much easier to read your explanation than invest several minutes to understand your code.

Comment: @ole-begemann, the algorithm checks an array of hex values (20 times), if any of them match 0xFF it adds a different hex value into the appropriate array.

Answer (score 3):

If I haven't made a mistake:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    BOOL canDoSomething = YES;

    for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
        if (a[j] == 0xFF || b[i+j] == a[j]) {
            c[j] = b[i+j];
            if (d[j] == 0xFF) {
                d[j] = c[j];
            }
        }
        else {
            canDoSomething = NO;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (canDoSomething) {
         [self doSomething];   
         break;     
         // according to your latest edit: continue; i+=19; 
         // continue does nothing as you use it, and i+=19 makes i >= 20
    }
}
```

It's what your code does. But it looks like it will cause index out bounds exception.
Perhaps nested loop's clause should look like

```
for (NSUInteger j = 0; i+j < 20; j++)
```

Comment: i'll try it out and post back with the results, and thank you for the example.  ;-)

Comment: thanks, but it didn't work. I could post the actual loop for you to see, but it's well over 100 lines long. :-.

Comment: mine works fine (the big ugly one); the examples here and the ones i've been experimenting with seem to loop fine, although apparently not in the same way — i can't really seem to grasp why, since the example you posted looks like it should work just fine. :-/ I noticed one thing in my example that was different, and that's where the last loop ends there's only on } and then the call to the method.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use recursion.

Declare another method:

```
-(BOOL)doSthWithA:(int*)a B:(int*)b C:(int*)c D:(int*)d Integer:(int)j AnotherInteger:(int)i {

  // end of recursion 
  if(j == 20) {
    return YES;
  }

  if (a[j] == -0x1 || b[i+j] == a[j]) {
     c[j] = b[i+j];
     if (d[j] == -0x1) {
         d[j] = c[j];
     }
     return doSthWithA:a B:b C:c D:d Integer:j+1 AnotherInteger:i;
  }
  else return NO;
}
```

and in your code:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  if(doSthWithA:a B:b C:c D:d Integer:0 AnotherInteger:i;) {
    [self doSomething];  
    i+=19;
  }
}
```

It probably can be all done better, but that translates your code into a more compact form.

Comment: Recursion will work, but it seems to be a bit overkill when a simple nested loop will suffice.

Comment: @MaciejTrybiło, i think anything would be better than what i have currently. thanks for providing an example for me. I'll post back after I have a chance to try it out.

Comment: Unfortunately none of these worked; I tried for hours to get it to work like the long version but no dice :-/